# Maya export issues into unity

Tags: export, maya

I have modelled a character. It is textured, rigged, skinned and animated. The animation works fine in Maya (2014) but I have been running into lots of issues when I try to export it. When I export it into Unity or Blender, the mesh turns into a sphere. I have tried exporting it as fbx, ma and mb files. The animation is still there. I have no useless nodes in my outliner and have followed tutorials to ensure that I was choosing the right export options but to no avail. It's only happening to this particular model. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you are selecting the mesh(s), make sure you select/export entire hierarchy. Can you share a screenshot of the outliner with the relevant nodes expanded?

Comment: thanks for your response. It's fixed now. It was to do with the outliner like you suggested.

Comment: I'll get a screenshot up with the before and after, after this game jam for anyone else having this issue.

Comment: If its fixed then you dont have to share. I will add that comment as an answer. Vote up and accept it if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

A common mistake is to not have the right nodes selected, especially if selected from the viewport.

When you are selecting the mesh(s), make sure you select/export entire hierarchy.

Hope this helps.